# Apache configuration file for Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, htaccess, apache, .htaccess

I have installed Magento 2.4 on Apache 2 sever running on Ubuntu 20.x

When I try to load the magento root directory on browser, I get

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I have the .htaccess (default file created by install) like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Can someone help me understand what this is trying to do?

My understanding is, this is looking for index.php file (which is not present in the root installation directory - and thus the error).

I have a feeling that the error has to do something with the line

```
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 should be loaded by apache from the `magento_root/pub` directory. In Magento 2.4.2 this has been enforced by a new `magento_root/.htaccess` file. The rewrite rules here are attempting to rewrite all access to `magento_root` to `magento_root/pub`

You should configure the document root of your apache magento 2 server configuration to

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/magento2/pub"
```

Where */var/www/html/magento2* is the path to your `magento_root` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Now I am getting MIME type related error 

'The resource from “http://127.0.0.1/magento2/static/version1616011116/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)'